# Like/send button closing by itself after login

Tags: javascript, facebook-like

I'm trying to implement the like button on this site www.urlc.be
I have the SDK and an app_id.

When I click the 'like' or 'send' button a popup opens and closes instantly without error.

Can you help me make it work

Thanks.

UPDATE : CODE

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '437569932948538', // App ID
      //channelUrl : 'http://www.urlc.be/static/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
```

page to like

```
<fb:like send="true" href="http://www.urlc.be/myurl/" layout="button_count" width="450" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

Comment: Maybe if you provide some code people might be able to help

Comment: That's why I wrote the website URL.

Comment: links can become invalid, which is why code helps, especially if someone else has a similar issue and your site is no longer active.Also if someone else has a similar issue, they might want to confirm that their initial code is the same as your initial code. This way they know if an answer is applicable to their situation rather than having to trawl through the source code of your site.

Comment: Can you give an example of where this happens? I tried liking http://www.urlc.be/news/read/294/ and it worked without any issues.

Comment: I tried with the same link and it doesn't work with me. If I click on 'send' button I have a popup window opening and closing instantly all by itself. If I'm not logged in facebook the popup stays open asking me to sign in in. When signed in the popup closes and nothing appens.I'm using google chrome.

Comment: With firefox I have the same issue but sometimes I have 'The page at http://www.urlc.be/news/read/294/ could not be reached.'

Comment: I think the problem is solved. Google chrome was blocking facebook cookies...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was from google chrome not accepting cookies from Facebook.